# Case Sensitive with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

I create database with Entity Framework CodeFirst. I look other questions but any of them has not spesific answer.I try to save this two KEY's as a different rows to my table.:

12E60AED-7491-49B3-8006-78ECEA63B376
12e60aed-7491-49b3-8006-78ecea63b376

This is my class for attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class CaseSensitive : Attribute
    {
            public CaseSensitive()
            {
                IsEnabled = true;
            }
            public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my db model:

```
[Table("StandardBusinessDocument", Schema = "EFatura")]
    public class StandardBusinessDocument{
        [Key]
        [Column( TypeName= "varchar" , Order =0), MaxLength(36) ]
        [CaseSensitive]
        public string StandardBusinessDocumentGuid { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(TypeName = "bit", Order = 1)]
        public Boolean StandardBusinessDocumentType { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar"), MaxLength(4)]
        public string Code{ get; set; }
}
```

An this is entityContex:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add
                (new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<CaseSensitive, bool>
                ("CaseSensitive", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().IsEnabled));
}
```

But it doesnt work, when I look caseSensitive from tableDesigner-Collation CaseSensitive is disabled. How can I work it?

Comment: *CaseSensitive is unable* - do you mean *enabled*, *disabled*?

Comment: @Rafalon Yess, thank you for correction

Comment: You should change the collate of the field in the sql.Here is a link that do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233168/define-sql-table-primary-key-as-case-sensitive-using-entity-framework-code-first and a list of the collate list is provided here: http://zarez.net/?p=1893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find answer. I write CaseSensitive after  [Key] and this work. I don't know how..:

```
[Key]
[CaseSensitive]
[Column( TypeName= "varchar" , Order =0), MaxLength(36) ]
public string StandardBusinessDocumentGuid { get; set; }
```

Comment: Because you are giving an attribute to your property thats why it works .